# Is there a way to export MySQL database to avoid syntax errors?

Tags: mysql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to move database from one server to another, both using different MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions. Everything goes successful but on some pages there is an error saying:

```
SQL/DB Error -- [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range, p.name, p.description, p.height, p.width, p.depth, p.active, pc.product_c' at line 1]
```

I cannot find anything that would be wrong in the SQL file. This is the link with the error (as you can see, overall it works and reads, some pages have errors).

[Link to Test Version](http://theglitchmagazine.com/colours/product.php?product_id=1)

[Link to Screenshot of Export Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxvuH.png)

My question is: **Is there a way to export SQL from this older database so it will be working?** It's fully working on the previous website so I'm assuming these are compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

From the error that you are getting

`right syntax to use near range, p.name, p.description`

`range` is a reserved keyword http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

So within the query you need to use backtick for that column name

```
`range`
```

Comment: I see. So in order for it to work I need to replace each and every `range` within the SQL file. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't need to modify .php files at all, do I?

Comment: where your queries are written ? If its on PHP file then you need to change there.

Comment: all you really need are some backticks - but it's good practice to avoid reserved words in table/column identifiers